# input bar covers text in mobile but not on desktop

Tags: html, css

I cant click on the first link. It seems like something is covering up the link, but I don't see what is. The first image is on my phone. This is the one that I cant get it clicked. The desktop is fine. I thought the search bar is covering it up, so I increase bottom margin to see if it'll help. It didn't. I can click Join, I can't click login. And when I log in, the same problem persists with other links on the top.

[edit]
I'm using this as the sliders on the right. http://plugins.adchsm.me/slidebars/usage.php I didn't change much from the stylesheet.

stylesheet:

```
    .search {
float: left;
position: relative;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
font-size: 12px;
color: #fff;
margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.nav-header {
display: block;
padding: 3px 15px;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 20px;
color: #999999;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
text-transform: uppercase;
}
.nav-list .nav-header {
margin-left: -15px;
margin-right: -15px;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.sb-slidebar {
height: 100%;
overflow-y: auto;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
z-index: 0;
visibility: hidden;
background-color: #222;
}
```

view. This is for the right side of the menu bar:

```
        <div class="sb-slidebar sb-right">  
            <div class="search">
                <?php echo CHtml::form(Yii::app()->createUrl('site/search'),'get') ?>
                <?php echo CHtml::textField('search_key', '',array('placeholder'=>'search')) ?>
                <button type="submit">
                </button>
                <?php echo CHtml::endForm() ?>
                </div>
            <?php 
            $this->widget(
                    'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
                    array(
                            'type' => 'list',
                            'items'=>array(
                                //array('icon'=>'user','label'=>"Profile", 'url'=>array('/user/profile/view','id'=>Yii::app()->user->getId(),'hello' => Yii::app()->user->first_name), ),
                            array('label'=>'Hi Guest'),                         
                            array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/signin'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                            array('label'=>'Join', 'url'=>array('/site/signup'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                            ),
));?>
</div>
```

[image][image]

Comment: Some code, links or fiddle, perhaps? nobody knows what code you're using, just from these snippets shown in image.

Comment: i did add some css and code. Well, now I added a bit more, maybe that will help. There isn't much because there really isn't much, just an input bar and two links.

Comment: Any way you can link us to a live example or a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the static height & bottom margin off of .search? It looks like the div is overlaying the links.